# nginx - userdir with user permissions

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions, users

What I want to do is have the usual server running user files like this:

`http://users.example.com/~user1/stuff.php`

which would be stored somewhere in `/home/user1/www` or something like that, but running with that user's permissions. So, scripts in the `/home/user1/www` directory can't access files/folders in the `/home/user2/www` directory (unless UNIX permissons permit it).

I [read a solution](http://www.sebdangerfield.me.uk/2012/05/nginx-and-php-fpm-bash-script-for-creating-new-vhosts-under-separate-fpm-pools/) using vhosts and a new pool for each vhost, but for hundreds of users that's probably to heavie. Is there any workaround?

Note that I'm running nginx in a Raspberry Pi, so this is just a home project, nothing really serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nginx doesn't run php directly, but instead forwards requests to a php application, you care what the php binary is running as. I'm assuming you're running php-fpm, but the general idea isn't specific to php-fpm.

The [configuration page for php-fpm](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) shows the directives that can be set. We're interested in the `user` and `group` params, as they control what user and group the php instances will run as (and therefore what permissions the script will run as). The `chroot` directive may also be of interest in creating a secure system (you may want to restrict each user to only the files available in `/home/user1/www`, not higher in the directory hierarchy).

As you can see, they're set on a per-pool basis.

So you could create several pools, one per user, and have each run under that user and group. You could also chroot to that user's webroot. This is the solution you linked.

But since you have to set up a new php-fpm pool for every user, it's not something you can do on-demand. Instead, make creating the php-fpm pool part of your user creation process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But isn't having 1 pool per user expensive?

Comment: Further reading confirmed that a large number of pools can be efficient if the PM is set to ondemand. This way processes will only be created if there are requests. Typically there are few requests to this kind of pages. I'll accept your answer